# How to call the products which do tedious tasks quickly and easily?

Tags: word-usage

If the products or apps that automatically do tedious tasks quickly and easily, are these usually expressed as "인스턴트 XX" or "원터치 XX," in Korean? E.g. "인스턴트" 음성 녹음 앱, "원터치" 기록 앱. If there are more natural words, please teach me. Thank you.

Comment: Some words you can try: 간편, 자동, 빠른.

Answer (score 1):

No. South Koreans would use "스마트" for that.
Yeah, it's literally the English word "Smart"